# How to pass ID inside shortcode - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, shortcode

I need to modify one of my theme's shortcodes so that I can pass a class ID to the columns. I need to be able to put in an extra parameter `id=""` and then put in any ID.

These are the shortcodes:

```
if (!function_exists('two_col_50_50_col1')) {
    function two_col_50_50_col1($atts, $content = null) {
        return '<div class="two_columns_50_50 clearfix"><div class="column1"><div class="column_inner">' . do_shortcode($content)  .   '</div></div>';
    }
}
add_shortcode('two_col_50_50_col1', 'two_col_50_50_col1');

if (!function_exists('two_col_50_50_col2')) {
    function two_col_50_50_col2($atts, $content = null) {
        return '<div class="column2"><div class="column_inner">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div></div></div>';
    }
}
add_shortcode('two_col_50_50_col2', 'two_col_50_50_col2');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to shortcodes like this:

```
// [bartag foo="foo-value"]
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'foo' => 'something',
    'bar' => 'something else',
), $atts );

return "foo = {$a['foo']}";
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

So for your code it would be like:

```
if (!function_exists('two_col_50_50_col1')) {
 function two_col_50_50_col1($atts, $content = null) {
 $a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'id' => ''
), $atts );
 return '<div class="two_columns_50_50 clearfix '.$a['id'].'"><div        
 class="column1"><div class="column_inner">' . do_shortcode($content)  .   '</div></div>';
 }
  }
 add_shortcode('two_col_50_50_col1', 'two_col_50_50_col1');

 if (!function_exists('two_col_50_50_col2')) {
 function two_col_50_50_col2($atts, $content = null) {
  $a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'id' => ''
), $atts );
  return '<div class="column2 '.$a['id'].'"><div class="column_inner">' .      do_shortcode($content) . '</div></div></div>';
}
}
add_shortcode('two_col_50_50_col2', 'two_col_50_50_col2');
```

And you can call the shortcode like:

```
[two_col_50_50_col2 id="something"]
```

For detailed info on wordpress shortcodes read this documentation: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: Well he wanted the ID in class attribute. So i have added the value of ID  `$a['id']` in the class attribute of 1st html element.